# What is a word that encompasses the sentence "I don't mind asking for help when I am struggling"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a college essay and I would like to make it more concise by finding a word that encompasses the sentence

> I don't mind asking for help when I am struggling.

I would like this word to substitute the bracketed portion of the sentence,

> My curiosity to learn beyond the syllabus and [the fact that I don't mind asking for help when I am struggling] are 2 traits that helped me stand out in their class.

Comment: Your tag says you're looking for a single word. Would a phrase work? In any event, one more to concise way of saying "the fact that I don't mind asking for help when I am struggling" is "to seek help when needed." Your sentence would read "My curiosity to learn beyond the syllabus and to seek help when needed are 2 traits that helped me stand out in their class.

Comment: @Richard Kayser I would put it a slightly different way since *curiosity* doesn't seem to work well with the second phrase: *My curiosity to learn beyond the syllabus and willingness to seek help when needed are 2 traits that helped me stand out in their class.*

Comment: @NikhilAnand Yep, that reads well. Good comment. I could (should) have set off "and to seek help when needed" with commas: "My curiosity to learn beyond the syllabus, and to seek help when needed, are 2 traits that helped me stand out in their class. Also, the OP should replace "2" with "two".

Comment: If this is for a C.V., I suggest the phrase "I'm always open to feedback"

Comment: What are you implying? That the person is **practical**? **Secure**? **Humble**? **Impatient**? **Unimaginative**? What is it that you want conveyed by "not minding"? I know you're likely thinking of a positive trait, but I mentioned the rest to indicate the breadth of possibility.

Answer (score 1):

What you intend to say is that you have no airs of superiority, and you don't hesitate to ask for help, when in need.

There's no single word to replace the bracketed portion, but  to convey the implied sentiment, you might replace the bracketed portion with
"**my [unassuming](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unassuming) humility**".

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!